# Delete file from ftp if its older than a given time with PERL script

Tags: perl, ftp

i try to delete a given file from my ftp server if its older than a given value like 2 minutes for example

i have it like this atm. the script runs perfectly but the part where it should check the files does not work.

my code so far:

```
my $max_time = 120;

if (!&ftp'get($lockkudatei, $Path.$tmpfile, 0)) {
    &timedprint("No excisting Lock file");
} else {
    my $file_ku_mdtm = $ftp->mdtm($lockkudatei);

    if( time - $file_ku_mdtm >= $max_time ) {
        if(&ftp'delete("$lockkudatei")) {
            &timedprint("Lock file deleted");
        } else {
            &timedprint("Lock file could not be deleted");
            &dodie("Lock file could not be deleted");
        }
    } else {
        &dodie( "No excisting Lock file\n");
    }
}
```

dodie:

```
 sub dodie {
     ($msg) = @_;
     #$t=localtime(time());
     #print STDOUT "\nt: $msg";
     print STDOUT "\nERROR:$msg";
     die( $msg );
 }
```

timedprint:

```
sub timedprint {
     ($msg) = @_;
     #$t=localtime(time());
     #print STDOUT "\nt: $msg";
     print STDOUT "\n$msg";
 }
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "does not work". What result do you expect? What happens actually? /// For debugging, print out or otherwise log the values of the relevant variables/expressions.

Comment: `&ftp'get(...)`. Wow. I haven't seen that style syntax in over 20 years. Isn't it from perl 4? Please say this is ancient code that got dumped on you and not something written recently...

Comment: it does not delete the file on the server. i cant print out values because the script runs totaly in the background and i have no idea where it gets triggered because its no cronjob or something. and i have no idea the script is from 2002 and now they issue network problems where a .lock file remains on the ftp. therefor i need to check how old the file is and deletet it evantually and that doesnt work

Comment: *"now they issue network problems where a .lock file remains on the ftp"* So this is a hack to "fix" a bug elsewhere. It sounds like this system is a mess.

Comment: Your code has `print` statements. Find out what is being printed by `timedprint` and tell us, please.

Comment: @Borodin the system is no mess but when they have electricity problems ot happens that the files dont get deleted. in normal case they get deleted at the end of the script, this works perfectly. i have no output because i have nothing in my console that is printed, i dont know why. should i post the whole script??

Comment: @Bertl: That's a problem that should be solved by an uninterruptible power supply. You shouldn't rely on a process deleting its own temporary files anyway, but on Linux you should delete the file as soon as it is created; it will then remain accessible until the file handle is closed.

Comment: @Borodin ...why wasnt i thinking about that.. but im a software engineer and when the customer wants to have that in the programm like that its not my job to tell them to fix their network..

Comment: Yes, I suggest you post the whole program if it's small enough.

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at the question [*How to create temporary files on linux that will automatically clean up after themselves no matter what?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889277/) in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9889520/622310).

Comment: Thats a total different topic?! the code is 400 lines long.. i guess thats too long. i found out that mdtm is only for newer perl versions. i have perl version 5 on that machine. but i cant upgrade because there are to many perl scripts on the server and i cant redo all of them. does somebody have a different solution instead of mdtm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilt the script with the Net::FTP Module and cleared old code totaly. and now it works with the mdtm() from the module.

works fine:

```
my $file_ku_mdtm = $ftp->mdtm($lockkudatei);
if( time - $file_ku_mdtm >= $max_time ) {}
```